# How can I get a list of students from this database schema?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following database:

| Student |
| --- |
| StudentID |
| Name |
| LastName |

| Grade |
| --- |
| GradeId |
| Name |

| GradeInstance |
| --- |
| GradeInstanceId |
| GradeId |
| Name |
| Year |

| StudentInstance |
| --- |
| StudentInstanceId |
| GradeInstanceId |
| StudentInstanceId |

How can I retrieve a list of students from a given grade instance?

I'm using Entity Framework as my ORM so what would the LINQ query be like?

Edit: I need to return **Student** objects, not **StudentInstance** object because those don't contain the attributes I need to fill the GUI with.

So something like this doesn't work for me, unless I'm missing something here.

```
dbContext.StudentInstances.Where(s => s.GradeInstanceId == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from s in dbContext.Student
join si in dbContext.StudentInst on s.StudentID equals si.StudentInstanceID
join g in dbContext.Grade on si.GradeInstanceID equals g.GradeID
where g.Name = ...
select s;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started....

```
    public static List<Student> GetStudents(int gradeId)
    {
        using (var context = new Entities())
        {
            List<Student> myList = (from s in dbContext.Student 
join si in dbContext.StudentInst on s.StudentID equals si.StudentInstanceID
join g in dbContext.Grade on si.GradeInstanceID equals g.GradeID
where g.GradeId = gradeId
select s).ToList();

         return myList;
        }
    }
```

Using slightly modified [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573234/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-students-from-this-database-schema/5573308#5573308) :D

Comment: Not quite, this returns all students. I need only the students that are in the StudentInstance table that have X number as GradeInstanceId

Answer (score 0):

you could add a navigation property to your GradeInstance Entity to the collection of Student entities related to it (you actually have the possibility to do that from the Add Association wizard), then you could acess it simply with: `gradeInstance.Students`

Hope this helps